# Multi-colored lines only on screen when booting 17" iMac Core Duo 1.83Ghz

Tags: imac, startup, screen

New to StackExchange/Ask Different. Been a lurker for a long time, this is my first question/discussion. I hope somebody might point me in the right direction.

I was recently given a couple old iMacs that were going to be thrown away by a family member. The others all work fine after a format and memory upgrade. However, one of them does not. It is a 17" iMac Intel Core Duo 1.83Ghz. [Here is a link to the exact model info](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac_cd_1.83_17.html).

On bootup, I get the normal Apple start sound, but the screen only displays multi-colored lines. Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm9gb.jpg). I pulled the plastic bezel off, and tried removing the screen panel, and reseating the screen cable. I also removed and reseated the memory, and tried resetting NVRAM, all with no change. I don't need to worry about losing any data on this system, I will format it and clean install OSX when I fix the screen.

What should I try next to figure out what is causing the screen issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Probably a hardware issue either with the GPU or something between the GPU and the screen (screen itself, cable, etc.) dying. I know you reseated the screen and cable, but if said components are failing/have failed that won't be enough.

If you have an external monitor, try plugging it in and see if it works. If so, run [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) and see what it reports back. If you GPU is indeed dying, chances are this won't work. [To my knowledge](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/iMac_Intel_17%22) the GPU is attached permanently to the logic board, so you can't replace it.

Comment: Thanks very much for the info. I will try running an external display and see what happens.  I suppose I could get a used logic board on ebay fairly easily to replace it.  I will try the Hardware Test first though. Thanks!

Comment: @EvanGrist True, but given the age, it's probably not worth it, especially if you have more than 1.

Comment: Well unfortunately the power supply on the other one just died! I may just end up sell these for parts.

Comment: @EvanGrist If you're inclined, you [can replace the power supply](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+17-Inch+Power+Supply+Replacement/894) from the one with the dead GPU.